Why does "Apply pose as rest pose" actually just reset the mesh to the original rest pose? How can I apply a new pose?
Other threads don't seem to have my issue, or I'm not finding them. I have a video to show exactly what I'm talking about.

Video: https://youtu.be/Xw67Svycj2I
I have a pose, set with the skeleton, but when I "Apply pose as rest pose" it resets the skeletal mesh to the A-post. I want to be able to apply the pose and actually keep it in the SM.

The rest pose is your armature with no transforms on the bones. See it as your default pose from which any keyframe and deformations are calculated.
To set a pose as a rest pose means to change that point of reference, and therefore all the underlying transforms operated by keyframes, and deformations on meshes bound to that armature. But since you made that pose your new rest pose, it also means that the way your armature is right now is with no transforms. No transforms means no deformation, so your mesh is doing exactly what you ask from it: nothing.
If you really want to preserve the mesh as it was posed before applying the pose as rest pose: first apply the mesh object's armature deform modifier. Then apply the pose as rest pose. Then if you still want to animate, add the modifier again.
That being said, looking at the pose in your screenshot, it doesn't look like one that should be a rest pose. Why do you try to apply that?
If you need to come back to that pose often, you should store it with the asset browser (+ pose library addon if still needed).
Your rest pose should be neutral, fit for skinning and handling rigging technicalities. And you can't change it as you create animations.

This is the answer.
But to answer your question. I don't want it as an actual rest pose. I'm trying to import a neutral, non combative sword hold pose to Unreal. I couldn't figure out how to actually save the pose so I tried to just apply it as the base pose.
I managed to get it to Unreal but I don't really know how. I don't see a way to save poses or anything.

That's a totally different matter then x) From a data perspective, there isn't really a "pose" data in the same way we could have a mesh or an image. It's actually a one-frame-long animation. So getting a pose out of Blender into another software is the same workflow as exporting/importing any animation.
